# Inner functions reference parameter of last call

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

It seems that variables in this function are being overwritten with each call to edit() function.

```
function edit(el)
{
    $edit_img = $(el);
    $btn = $('<img width="15" height="15" src="images/add.png">');

    $edit_confirm = $edit_img.parent();

    $edit_confirm.append($btn);

    function restore_span()
    {
        $edit_img.show();

        $btn.remove();
    }

    $btn.click(restore_span);

    $edit_img.hide();
}
```

Edit function is called from this onclick handler:

```
<img src = "images/edit-icon.png" width = "15px" height = "15px" onclick="edit(this)" />
```

When invoking edit() on several images like the one above only image, which was created most recently gets removed.

How should I modify this function in order to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike PHP, variables in JavaScript are not implicitly local to the block or function.

To declare variables as local to the function scope, use [`var` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

```
function edit(el) {
    var $edit_img = $(el), // use them with comma
        $btn = $('<img width="15" height="15" src="images/add.png">');
    var $edit_confirm = $edit_img.parent(); // or just multiple times
    $edit_confirm.append($btn);
    $btn.click(function restore_span() {
        $edit_img.show();
        $btn.remove();
    });
    $edit_img.hide();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Before I've learnt jQuery, I did always use var, but since then I completely forgot to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Use `var $btn` instead of `$btn` (and also for other variables)

When you write
`var $btn` - you create local variable 
when without `var` - it is global

So in your case you replace each time these variables (for example `$edit_img` that is used in restore function)